# Watching form validation in angular isolated scope

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

When using a form in angular, if the scope is all on "one level", I can use a watch on the form variable in the controller to see when the validation has changed:
http://plnkr.co/edit/s4s2FeRDc6hEJHUqQLZO?p=preview
(watch in the console)

However, if an ng-include is used, this seems to break the watch:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YFx22DiB0WA9UyNa80kR?p=preview

It seems that the isolated scope breaks things, or, more likely, I have... How can I make this work?

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `ng-controller="form"` to the `ng-form` element instead of having it declared in the element with `ng-include`. It seems `ng-include` creates an isolated scope for the inner component, thus the form will not be visible to the outside.

*Edit: typo*

Comment: Thanks Michael! I had always defined the controller at this level as it seemed cleaner and often saw this "strange" behaviour without knowing why. There was usually a work-around (pass the value to the function), but for watch this wasn't available.